# increase size of jInternalFrame when click on video in java

Tags: java, swing

question--

1. i have vlcj media player.
2. canvas, contentpane, mdiaplayer in the code of vlcj.
3. i have `JInternalFrame`.
   4, it shows videos.
4. but i want that if i click on running video in `JInternalFrame`, the size of `JinterFrame` should increase (full size) and again click on running video, size should become normal.

HOW CAN I DO THIS????  bcz there is no `ActionListener` which i can apply on running mp4 video screen in java???? `JInternalFrame` can increase size without video but with running video. I cant find solution to increase size of `JInternalFrame` when click on it.?????????????

my code ----->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        canvas1 = new Canvas();
        canvas1.setBackground(Color.black);
        contentPane1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane1.add(canvas1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane1.setTransferHandler(new MyTransferHandler());

        MyMouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
        canvas1.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        canvas1.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);


        jInternalFrame1.setContentPane(contentPane1);
        factory1 = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        mediaPlayer1 = factory1.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

        videoSurface1 = factory1.newVideoSurface(canvas1);
        mediaPlayer1.setVideoSurface(videoSurface1);
        mediaPlayer1.getPosition();
        mediaPlayer1.getTime();
        mediaPlayer1.setPlaySubItems(true);
```

Comment: Beware, that mixing heavy and lightweight components can still cause unexpected and troublesome z-ordering issues

Comment: What does `MyMouseAdapter` do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a normal `MouseListener` to the `Canvas` to detect the clicks. Then resize your frame however you want.

```
canvas1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        // Resize however you want
    }
});
```

If your listener is not working, you may need to invoke *both* of...

```
mediaPlayer.setEnableMouseInputHandling()
mediaPlayer.setEnableKeyInputHandling()
```

...when you create your media player.